# Selecting the newest entry of each day

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the simple class

```
public class Data
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public object Content;
}
```

Now I have a `IEnumerable<Data>` called `datas` and I want Linq to sort the older items of each day out. Such that if there are items of the same day, I am only interested in the latest item of that day.

Is this possible with Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var result =
    datas
     //Group by day (we don't include time here)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date)
    //For each group (day), get most recent item (we include time here)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First()) 
    .ToList();
```

For more readability, you could also use `x.TimeOfDay` instead of `x.Date` in the `Select` statement.

Comment: One additional question: Is it possible to use the "sql" like syntax to write this peace of code? ala: `var result = from data in datas .... select data`

Comment: I don't really use sql like syntax. So I am not sure if you can translate everything into that syntax. I am not sure if it can be done better that this: `from data in datas group data by data.Date.Date into g select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date.TimeOfDay).First()`

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
var result = from x in datas
        group x by x.Date.Date into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
var result = datas.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date)
            .Select(g => g.Where(x => x.Date == g.Max(y => y.Date))
            .First());
```

Comment: The type of `x` is `Data`, not `DateTime`.

Comment: You need to select `Date` from `x`, and then call `Max`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad You mean `x.Date.Max()` ?

Comment: You need something like this: `.Select( g => g.Select(x => x.Date).Max())`

Comment: Also my suggestion `.Select( g => g.Select(x => x.Date).Max())` is also wrong. I made a mistake suggesting it.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Ok, I' have test it now, it work! Thank you for remak :)

Comment: I am not sure you can use `Max` because now your query returns a list of `DataTime` objects, not `Data` objects.

Comment: You probably can solve this by using `MaxBy` from [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ).

Comment: @YacoubMassad I will see and thank you for your very important remarks :)

Comment: Please note that you need to group by `x.Date.Date` because you don't want to consider time of day here.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Ok I did it, Thanks again :)